# Intellij Create Test missing JUnit

Tags: intellij-idea

I try to create an test class and test it using JUnit, but in my Intellij is missing JUnit library.

[image]

What I need to do to have at library option with JUnit?

Comment: Do you create the test in the Java code? Do you have JUnit library present in the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Add `junit-jupiter` artifact in Maven

If using [Apache Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) to configure your project, and writing [JUnit 5 *Jupiter*](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/j-introducing-junit5-part1-jupiter-api/) to write you tests, add a dependency to your project.

JUnit 5.4 simplified things by providing this new Maven artifact, [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter). This one aggregate artifact provides all you need to write and run JUnit 5 tests. Previous to 5.4, you had to add multiple artifacts — confusing and messy.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is an example, an entire POM file. I started an app using the [`maven-archetype-quickstart`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart) artifact. Next I changed all the versions numbers to the latest, as of this week shown here. Lastly, I replaced the old JUnit 4 dependency with the new JUnit 5 dependency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>method-lister</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>method-lister</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--  <groupId>junit</groupId>-->
        <!--  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>-->
        <!--  <version>4.11</version>-->
        <!--  <scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

## JUnit plugins

Be sure the IntelliJ plugin for JUnit is installed *and* enabled. Verify the checkmark is checked, meaning enabled. (You can disable unneeded plugins to save memory and launch time.)

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ > Preferences > Plugins, filtered to show only JUnit-related plugins]

## `Generate Test` dialog

Your IntelliJ 2019.1 dialog for `Generate` > `Test…` should look like this.

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ > Generate > Test… dialog box]

Comment: JUnit Plugin was disabled, but now it works. Thank you!